# spray-testkit with scalatest, status doesn't work

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-test

I am trying to test a POST spray-route with scalatest which require a mandatory parameter adId. And Cannot make it work. My code follows

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.event.LoggingReceive
import akka.testkit.{TestProbe}
import com.ss.rg.service.ad.AdImporterServiceActor.{GetImportStatus, StatusOfImport}
import org.scalatest.{MustMatchers, WordSpecLike}
import spray.http.{StatusCodes, MediaTypes}
import spray.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest

class AdServiceApiTest extends  WordSpecLike with MustMatchers with ScalatestRouteTest{
 "AdService REST api " must{
   "POST for import witout mandatory parameters should fail with " in{
      val p = TestProbe()
      val addressServiceMock = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[AdServiceActorMock],p.ref))

      Post("/service/ad/import") ~> new AdServiceApi(addressServiceMock).route ~>check{
        handled must be(false)
        status must be (StatusCodes.BadRequest)
      }
    }
  }
```

The test fails but for a different reason

```
Request was rejected with List(MissingQueryParamRejection(adId))
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Request was rejected with List(MissingQueryParamRejection(adId))
    at spray.testkit.ScalatestInterface$class.failTest(ScalatestInterface.scala:25)
    at com.ss.rg.api.ad.AdServiceApiTest.failTest(AdServiceApiTest.scala:19)
    at spray.testkit.RouteResultComponent$RouteResult$$anonfun$response$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteResultComponent.scala:97)
    at spray.testkit.RouteResultComponent$RouteResult$$anonfun$response$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RouteResultComponent.scala:95)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at spray.testkit.RouteResultComponent$RouteResult$$anonfun$response$1.apply(RouteResultComponent.scala:94)
...
```

Seems that status hasn't been even checked. 
Second thing which is not fully cleared to me is how to actually set a adId parameter in spray-testkit? One way would be via setting the header but I wouldn't be surprised that a better way would exist.

Can somebody more experienced with spray-testkit comment?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a status - the route [rejected](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/key-concepts/rejections/#rejections) the request. You can access the rejection as `rejection` and assert that it's the type you expect. If you want to check what the browser would actually see you should wrap the route in a `handleRejections` directive using the default `RejectionHandler` (it's available implicitly) and then you'll be able to see the status code you'd expect. In that case `handled` will come out as `true` though (because the wrapped route will handle the request - by returning a response with a failed statuscode and an error message).

Comment: @Imm Ahh, ok. Make sense. Don't you know how to set prameter for POST, query string

Comment: Query strings I tend to just put in the url, e.g. `Post("/path/to?param=value", body)`. If you want a more structured approach you can use `Uri` to build up a URL from its individual components. The second parameter to `Post` can be a post body; it must have a marshaller in scope (so e.g. using `SprayJsonSupport` and a suitable `JsonFormat`).